# Notice: Undefined variable: status in C:\xampp\htdocs\liker2\liker.php on line 134 and on line 130

Tags: php, html, facebook, css

There is unknown error for me i can't fix this error can anyone help me Thanks this is a facebook auto liker website

```
    if(isset($_GET['type'])){
if($_GET['type'] == "status"){
$beranda = json_decode(get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/$user->id/statuses?fields=id,message&limit=7&access_token=$token"))->data;
    foreach($beranda as $id){
    $status .= '
    <section class="status">
    <section class="image">
    <img style="-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 37px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 37px;
border-top-left-radius: 37px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 37px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 37px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 37px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;"src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user->id.'/picture">
    </section>
    <section class="name">'.$user->name.'</section>
    <section class="message"><span class="color">'.$id->message.'</span></section> //// line 30///
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id->id.'">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"></form>
    </section>';   //// line 34///
    }
    }
```

Comment: i will send you my liker.php file you can check this

Answer (score 1):

Before you use `.=` you need to set variable.

```
$status = '';
...
$status .= '...';
```

Comment: Not work you can check my liker.php http://www12.uptobox.com/d/vuyqbarfeyoy22kqseczyctbn5oitjobhc7deurct4grts7tdxffu7z5/liker2.zip

Comment: i was use this if(isset($_GET['type'])){
if($_GET['type'] == "status"){
$beranda = json_decode(get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/$user->id/statuses?fields=id,message&limit=7&access_token=$token"))->data;
 foreach($beranda as $id){
  $status = 'isset';
 $status .= '   but error 130 still there